# How to print out the object value returned by SoapClient?

Tags: soap, php, soap-client

```
<?php
   $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/calculator?wsdl");   
   $result = $client->add(3,3); 

   echo $result;

?>
```

Getting error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

How can I print out the response from `SoapClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

```
print_r($result);
```

or [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

```
var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

The result is a stdClass object. You can "print" an object using print_r which is a utility you can use to inspect the members of the object:

```
print_r($result);
```